# How to get full Windows version using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following command to get some OS info:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -ComputerName $ComputerName |`
    Where{$_.PartialProductKey -and $_.Name -like "*Windows*"} | Select `
    @{Expression={$_.PSComputerName};Name="ComputerName"},`
    @{Expression={$_.Name};Name="WindowsName"} ,ApplicationID,`
    @{Expression={$_.DESCRIPTION};Name="Description"},`
    @{Expression={$LicenseStatus[$($_.LicenseStatus)]};Name="LicenseStatus"}
    Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName

**Result:**
ComputerName  : dev12
WindowsName   : Windows(R), ServerStandard edition
ApplicationID : 55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f
Description   : Windows(R) Operating System, RETAIL channel
LicenseStatus : Licensed
```

Anyway I can get it to say Windows 2012 or 2016 or whatever it is...? Windows(R) not to informative...

Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is this: `(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption`

Comment: Don't you get the required info from this line in your script?  `Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName`

Comment: Get-ComputerInfo works, was just wondering if I can get it all in the same command to speed up the process... (running on batch computers)  ty